# How can I remove "zombie entries" from login items when the controls are dimmed?

Tags: macos, login-items

How can I get rid of zombie entries in Login items?

In this case BambooCore App doesn't respond to the - control even when I select it. Also the hide checkbox is disabled on this item, just like the delete control.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (All Users) is a clue that the system has been instructed to make all users have this item and it's not something you would add or remove from a user account.

You could browse to /Library/StartupItems and just remove the Bamboo (or potentially Wacom) items by moving them to trash or uninstalling the software that put those items on the system.

To be complete, if there are other users on the Mac, they may need to re-add that program if they want to use it.

Answer (score 5):

It's far late, but I have discovered today, trying to remove a similar zombie item that you cannot remove items for ALL ITEMS when the padlock icon is closed. Open the padlock for any action that involves other users. That's all.

Comment: stupid to not see it, but that was also my problem

Comment: Whelp, totally overlooked that. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you don’t have permission to remove this item — are you on a restricted account? You could try to launch System Preferences with [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo), and then try again. Open Terminal, then type this:

`sudo open /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/`

You will have to enter your user password (which is not shown on screen).
Let me know if this works!

Comment: If this doesn't work - look for Wacom software related to their Bamboo stylus - it's possible a system wide installation has called for running drivers on all user accounts and you'll need to clean that up if it re-injects that item each boot.

Comment: sudo open -a "System Preferences"

Comment: just another way to do this :P

Answer (score 2):

Other applications add login items to `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`. You can remove them by just deleting the plist and restarting (logging out and back in isn't enough).

Answer (score 0):

After I "Click the lock to make changes" in the lower right cornet of the preference page, I was able to remove the "Bamboo Core"